# Roll back or flag neutral minor edit

Tags: discussion

[I recently came across a proposed edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4989454) that "improved" grammar and fixed a typo.

It's obviously too minor, but I'm more curious about:

- *Whether it was a good idea to roll the edit back.* The edit is neither an improvement or a degradation; aside from the one typo and a repeated word, there really was no difference in the posts.

  I rolled it back largely because having someone change your post without good reason can be annoying, and I didn't want the author to be annoyed.
- *Whether I should have flagged this kind of edit for moderator attention.* My reservation comes from the absurd number of such edits. I fear that if we flag even a small proportion of wrongly accepted edits the moderators will quickly be overwhelmed!

Comment: As one of the reviewers who approved I can see why you think this edit was too minor but in my opinion this mistakes were all things that could cause somebody looking at a post to by pass it as low quality. As the editor didnt make just one change (fix one typo), he fixed all the problems that were present in the post I felt that he deserved to have his review approved. Maybe others can weigh in here but I feel that was not a minor editor compared with a lot of the edits I have seen

Comment: "and you" → ". You" is not a fix; "what ever" → "whatever" is not a fix; adding quotes to "use case modelling" is not a fix; "knowing" → "knowledge on" is not a fix; removing non-printing spaces in Markdown is also *definitely* not a fix. // There are literally two changes that can be called fixes: "Requriments" → "Requirements" and "use" → "work".

Comment: @Veedrac but the fixes are improvements, and make the post better.

Comment: @Veedrac they may not be "fixes" for things that are super broken but they do make the question better when changed. These changes make a difference for somebody reading the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think Rolling Back a post due to a minor edit is really useful.

As it stands even if the minor edit did offer no improvement (which some may argue it does) you changing the post back to it's earlier state accomplishes nothing. The person who edited keeps their +2, the post has the same "minor mistakes" it had before. So nobody really wins. The only purpose of being able to flag and edit as "too minor" is to prevent the filling of the review queue with small edits. Rolling back the edit does nothing to further this goal as the edit has already been approved.

I believe that rolling back should be reserved for instances of invalid edits or vandalism, it just don't make sense to fill up a post's revision list with a even more minor rollback. Maybe I would understand rolling back if that took back the +2 the user got but it doesn't.

Comment: The decision to roll back wasn't anything to do with reputation of getting attention of the user. As I said, *"I rolled it back largely because having someone change your post without good reason can be annoying, and I didn't want the author to be annoyed."* As far as I can tell, the edit almost exclusively changed the *style*, which should be the domain of the author, and I am quite surprised that the overall opinion is that the new phrasing is in some way *better*. I personally prefer the old style. I would get very irritated if people changed my British spellings to American ones, [...]

Comment: [...] for instance, and I expected a similar opinion from the author with regards to this. Nevertheless, I understand that my opinion doesn't seem to be shared by the rest of Meta, so I shall leave it as that. Thank you.

Comment: I would definitely reject edits that changed British to American spellings or vice versa. But I certainly don't understand *taking offense* to it. Rolling it back would be a pretty dick move, as far as I'm concerned. As secretformula said, just because an edit was too minor and shouldn't have been accepted doesn't mean that it is a *harmful* edit and must be reversed. **My recommendation is not to take edits personally, @Veedrac.** And if you're worried about someone putting words in your mouth, do take note of the fact that the editor is clearly named below the post with a full edit history.

Comment: Being irritated isn't quite the same things as taking offense. I *certainly* don't agree that rolling back those types of edits to my posts is unreasonable. I want my posts to sound like I've written them, as long as I am the sole contributor, although I can't easily justify why I feel this way.